# Cant see output in terminal

Tags: jsp, servlets, terminal, osx-lion, tomcat

I am trying to run a jsp page from my browser, but why can't I see the output of System.out.println statements in terminal which I wrote in my Servlet?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I don't do Mac, so I don't know the details, but on Windows, the stdout appears in a different console. Perhaps you just need to switch the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should available in catalina.out log , read further [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html)

Comment: No, it does by default not end up in catalina.out. See also the doc which you linked youself (Ctrl+F on "swallowoutput")

Comment: alright, that's for old application but for tomcat6, output of System.out.println shown in catalina.out though

Comment: Ya all the logs are there in `/Developer/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/logs` but I want it to be displayed on terminal so that I can see it while running my file.

Comment: Do I have to run `catalina.out`? Tried `sh catalina.out`, says command not found.

Comment: catalina.out is a file, from my production deployment, printout of system.out.println is redirect to this file. You can view this file using tail in linux and it will show in the terminal. Sorry, i do not use mac os so i dont know what tools you can use to view the file.

Comment: `./startup.sh && tail -f ../logs/catalina.out` solved it. Thanks!